# build-impl.xml:1045: NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

After running the project I'm getting this error, My NetBeans is newly installed and I just copied the project files from my other laptop.

Here's my log details:

```
Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /EntJavaProject
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.javatpoint.MyListener
```

Comment: clean and rebuild maybe

Comment: I already did that still I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now, what I did was I deleted and copied again the .java files. I also realized that there's a duplicate file in src package so I think that's the reason why the project isn't deploying.